# How can I publish a PowerShell gallery module that depends on a platform-specific c# Nuget Package?

Tags: c#, powershell, nuget

I want to publish a PowerShell module to PowerShell gallery that depends on a [C# NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LibGit2Sharp).

I've done this in the past by simply bundling a cross-platform DLL of the dependency.
However, for LibGit2Sharp, this doesn't work, because it produces binaries that are platform-specific and can only be loaded if you build it against a specific platform (see [this thread](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1583)).

Could I somehow resolve the right artifact from NuGet and lazily download it instead of bundling it? Or should I maybe publish the PowerShell module itself on NuGet instead?

Comment: AFAIK PowerShell modules still have no support for non-PowerShell dependencies, so publishing the module wouldn't help. What I've done in the past for the admittedly more limited problem of 32-bit vs. 64-bit is to restore the package as part of a dummy C# project, then copy the outputs of that to my PowerShell module as a build step. Picking the correct version to load is done at runtime. However, in that case, PowerShell is the one loading the libraries, so it's easy for me to tell it where they are. If the libraries you're loading are located indirectly by another module, that's trickier.

Comment: I’ve been thinking about doing that - what cocerns me is that I would have to programmatically construct the [RID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) for the user’s OS and arch, but the docs explicitely state that RIDs should not be constructed programmatically. And I don’t even know how to reliably detect all the Linux distros. Alternatively, I could run a dotnet restore on first run (but I would still need the RID). But I don’t want to require the user to install the .NET SDK...